# Creating JSON Response in javax.ws.rs resource from Elasticsearch XContentBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, jackson, jax-rs, moxy

I am sure this is quite simple but I just haven't found the documentation or an example for it.  What I want to do is return a JSON object based on the XContent from an Elasticsearch **GetResponse**.    The code excerpt looks like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("get/{index}/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response get(@PathParam("index") String index, @PathParam("id") String id) {
        RestHighLevelClient client = ElasticAI.client();

        GetRequest req = new GetRequest(index, id);
        try {
            GetResponse resp = client.get(req, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            XContentBuilder xcb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
            resp.toXContent(xcb, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);

            return Response.ok(<what goes here?>).build();

        /// etc
```

What I am missing is how I get the XContentBuilder to produce an object that one of the standard converters supported by MOxy or Jackson can convert to APPLICATION_JSON.

Comment: I am not familiar with the ElasticSearch APIs, but I imagine at some point you will want to write out to an output stream. You can get the OutputStream by using StreamingOutput. I see that the jsonBuilder() method accepts an OutputStream that the XContentBuilder will write the results to, whatever those "results" are. Like I said, I'm not familiar with the library. Hope this helps though.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks for your input I did find a solution which I will post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

With some digging I did find a working solution although I don't know if this is how the library was meant to be used.   The winning solution (so far) is:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.Strings
...
return Response.ok(Strings.toString(xcb)).build();
```

The purpose of **XContent** structures are to have generalized objects similar to one of the JSON models except it appears **XContent** has an optimized binary form internally.  So faster I guess.   However I have found very little documentation on it other than the javadoc which is pretty sparse.   So if anyone can edit this to include a link to some normative text on this I sure would like to see it.

I am posting this here in case someone else is faced with this problem.  Looking high or low I don't see many comprehensible tutorials or examples of how to use Elasticsearch's XContent object this way.